# Modulus of the coefficients of a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $p(x)=a_nx^n+ \dotsb a_0 \in \mathbb C[x]$, and $|p(x)| \leqslant 1$ while $x \in D{_1}(0)$ , is it true that $|a_n| + \dotsb + |a_0| \leqslant 1$. I only know that taking $z=1$, can show that $|a_0+\dotsb+a_n| \leqslant 1$.

Comment: Seem's like an argument principle type problem.

Comment: Can you be more specific? How can I apply the argument principle? @JackyChong

Comment: What is $ D_1(0) $ ?

Comment: A ball centered at 0 of radius 1@user254665